# Find a non-square matrix $A$ such that $AA^T$ is non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to derive this.
My guess was to find a matrix that satisifes properties based on what we can conclude from the premise. (non-square matrix multipled by its tranpose gives a matrix with a non-zero determinant)

Let matrix $B = AA^T$

I've shown since the determinant of $B$ is nonzero, $B$ is nonsingular and hence invertible, so $AA^T$ should be row-equivalent to $I_{4}$ (identity matrix of size 4)

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What size factors are you working with? If there's no constraint, smaller is easier.

Comment: I'm working with A as 3x4.

Comment: Must you work with those sizes, or could you pick $A$ to be $1 \times 2$, the smallest possible size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a square invertible matrix and extend one row/column with zeros.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: if I can ask, how did you derive that?

Comment: @cdpp I'm not sure I can answer that, but I can try. It helps to know it has to a $(3\times4)$ by a $(4\times3)$. The other direction cannot produce a nonsingular matrix considering its rank is at most $3$. Then just come up with orthogonal vectors (used as rows in the first). But the simpler examples of that with all zeros in the end make you realize you could just say it in terms of a square matrix with an added column.

Comment: Just noticed your reply, thank you for the explanation! I noticed you pointed out rank, I'm still fairly new to subspaces and dimension, but is this a more formal way to tell if matrices are multiplicable?